# How to run / nest an external executable file from within a form in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

As the question states - How would I run / nest an external executable file from within a form in C#

Comment: What is the nature of the external executable? Is it a console application? Is it a .NET application? Does it use Windows Forms? Please provide additional information of this nature.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior It is a console application

Answer (score 2):

Use the [System.Diagnostics.Process.Start Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx) for this purpose.

Comment: Sorry, I mean actually run the program within a form, so part of the area of the form is taken up by the extenral application